# Is it possible to find generating functions of infinite sequences with Mathematica?

Tags: functions, summation

I'm trying to find the generating function of a sequence as $(0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots)$ but reading Mathematica's help on `FindGeneratingFunction[]` seems to tell me that it's possible to find only generating functions for finite sequences.

Comment: @Öskå $(0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots)$.

Answer (score 10):

It takes less work to use the definition of a generating function directly than by typing `FindGeneratingFunction`:

```
In[1]:= Sum[Mod[n, 2] x^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]

Out[1]= -(x/((-1 + x)*(1 + x)))
```

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to find generating functions using `FindGeneratingFunction`, but the finite list you provide to it has to be long enough:

```
seq = ConstantArray[{0, 1}, 5] // Flatten

Table[FindGeneratingFunction[seq[[;; n]], x], {n, 10}]
```

> [image: Out]

Answer (score 5):

```
p[z] = GeneratingFunction[Mod[n, 2], n, z]
CoefficientList[Normal@Series[p[z], {z, 0, 10}], z]

(* -(z/(-1 + z^2)) *)
(* {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your knowledge of other generating functions to construct a new one.

$ \frac{1}{1-x} =1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7 + x^8 + x^9 + x^{10}+...+ $

$ \frac{1}{1-x^2} = 1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + x^8 + x^{10} +...+ $

You just want to zero every even exponent in the first gf so subtraction is indicated.

$\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1-x^2}=-\frac{x}{(x-1) (x+1)} =x +x^3 + x^5 +...+$